# Short Story: Air being chargeable commodity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Back in the 80's I remember reading a science fiction short story in an issue of Playboy. I'd like to re-read it, if possible:

- author was a regular in Playboy during that time period
- the world was of the future
- people were charged for the air they breathed
- there was a count-down time display visible not only to the protagonist, but passers-by on the street as well
- don't remember if it was a hologram-like display, or on the wrist
- it may have been made into a movie within the last two decades, but unsure of that as well
- the protagonist was out of work and had no way to pay for more air and was hoping/begging for more time/air
- and finally, if I recall correctly, he didn't get any money from strangers, so died when his time/air ran out

Comment: Ah, that rings a bell. I think it has been asked here before. From what I can find, they point to the films _In Time_ and _The Price of Life_. But alas, no written works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Could be [**Time is money**](http://mandrake-comics.blogspot.com/2009/02/time-is-money-short-story-by-lee-falk.html)

> A Short Story by Lee Falk ill. F. Fredericks [First (and only?)
> published in Playboy december 1975] Courtesy:
> http://pjb.hopto.org/index.php?id=7&xr=19&page=1
>
> ...IT IS UNDERSTANDABLE that Tom was desperate. Near panic. His time was
> running out. To be more precise, his account at the Timebank had a
> balance of one hour, 14 minutes and 27 seconds. 1 hr 14 min 27 sec. If
> he could not make a deposit within that period, his account would be
> closed. At that moment, he would stop breathing. He would be dead.
> Perhaps this requires further explanation...

Comment: The movie is called "In Time" (2011) https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/

Comment: @yaroslav-kornachevskyi, nice find.

Comment: @jo1storm Is _In Time_ indeed based on this short story?

Comment: @SQB yes. That exact story.